# No panel, no window title bar, no unity launcher, can't move and resize windows

Tags: unity, launcher, desktop-environments

This problem actually appeared out of the blue. I've nearly exhausted every option I can find here, but it barely helped.

Here is my situation:

1. I tried `ccsm` to enable Ubuntu unity plugin, but every options are unchecked and it seems every time I configure and exit, it revert back to "everything unchecked".
2. My guest account seems working normally.
3. Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` also didn't help.
4. After trying `export DISPLAY=:0`

   ```
   sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   setsid unity
   ```

Unity launcher and the panel flashed for a split of a second and then disappeared again

Comment: Did you try `unity --reset` command?

Comment: Yes, the panel flashed and then went away :(

Comment: @Danibix here is the output: `unity-panrl-service stop/waiting`,`unity7 stop/waiting`, `unity-panel-service start/running process 3351`,`unity7 start/running, process 3363`

Comment: @Danibix I got this when I rebooted the system yesterday. I've currently installed mesa 17 dev version, but it worked as it should before. Should I revert it back to mesa 13 or something?

Comment: @Danibix is this really because of mesa 17? I have my guest account working fine though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55612/discussion-between-danibix-and-james-wong).

Comment: @Danibix unfortunately, it was not mesa's fault. Reverting back to mesa 13 didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 16.04 and these are the steps that worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```